# :not(:target) Selector Css

Tags: css, css-selectors, slide, target

I am making a basic slide demo and i got a problem with :not(:target) selector

i want to have my base slide at first. but when i try this code i got a blank page.

here my code and my css file.

thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>order form</title>

<link href="slide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 


</head>

<section>
 <header class="slide" id="foo">
 <h1>Θέμα ενότητας</h1>
 </header>
 <article class="slide" id="main">
 <h1>Σκυλος :</h1>

<a href="#setter" class="button">next</a>
 </article>



 <article class="slide" id="setter">
 <h1>Setter</h1>
 <p> </p>
 <a href="#Beagle" class="button">next</a>


 <footer class="slide" id="thankyou">
 <h1>Ευχαριστώ!</h1>
 <p>Closing credits</p>
 </footer>
</section>
```

*csss

```
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}



:not(:target){
    display:none;
}

:first-of-type:not(:target) {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a blank page because the `:not(:target)` applies to all elements.

You probably want `article:not(:target)` (*the same goes for the `:first-of-type` rule*)

Keep in mind though that if you make an overriding rule to display your first slide, it will always remain active.

---

To use this technique you will have to place your first slide as the last one (*in the DOM*). This way you can target it with `article:last-of-type` to show it at start and then use the more specific `article:target ~ article:last-of-type` to hide it when another one is active.

Something like this

```css
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}

article,
article:target ~ article:last-of-type{
    display:none;
}

article:target,
article:last-of-type{display:block;}
```

```html
<section>
  <header class="slide" id="foo">
    <h1>Θέμα ενότητας</h1>
  </header>
  
  <article class="slide" id="setter">
    <h1>Setter</h1>
    <p> </p>
    <a href="#Beagle" class="button">next</a>
  </article>

  <article class="slide" id="Beagle">
    <h1>Beagle</h1>
    <p> </p>
    <a href="#main" class="button">start</a>
  </article>

  <article class="slide" id="main">
    <h1>Σκυλος :</h1>
    <a href="#setter" class="button">next</a>
  </article>

  <footer class="slide" id="thankyou">
    <h1>Ευχαριστώ!</h1>
    <p>Closing credits</p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: @user3135218 updated with a working example (*and some required changes in the DOM*). Καλή συνέχεια :)